# how to read .txt file with a special format (each line contains headers and content) by python

Tags: python, txt

I have a `.txt` file with a special format, namely, each line contains a header and content. Please see the following picture. I want to ask how I can import this file into Python via open or `read_csv` functions. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tYHxE.png)

Comment: That looks like JSON. Open the file for reading, then use `json.loads(line)` for each line in the file.

Comment: I suggest you try something. First start by learning how to open a file and read each line. You could just print the line to the console to show that you read it correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your file is formatted as a JSON file. You can use Python's `json` module to handle JSON data as objects in Python using [`json.loads()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#json.loads)

Here's a usage example, it may require some tweaking depending on how your JSON file is structured.

```
import json

with open("file.json", "r") as dataFile:
    jsonData = json.loads(dataFile.read())
for item in jsonData:
    print(item["id"])
```

This code was tested with the following JSON data:

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Example 1"
    },
    {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Example 2"
    }
]
```

You can read more about the `json` module here: https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html